# Is it OK to use non-static Handler in non-Activity class?

Tags: android

I know why it's a good idea to use static Handlers (avoid memory leak while handler is being processed). However, most everything I've read seems to imply that it's to prevent leaking of the application/context. All the example code has an Activity or Service as the outer class. For example, this oft-linked post talks about leaking Contexts and Views (http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html). It ends with the quote "What's the bottom line? Avoid using non-static inner classes in an activity if instances of the inner class outlive the activity's lifecycle. Instead, prefer static inner classes and hold a weak reference to the activity inside."

Does this mean it's OK to use a non-static Handler if the owning class has no fields to anything related to Android lifecycle and is not an Activity/Service/etc.? I would have thought so, but the Lint warning doesn't care what class the outer class is. I understand I can still leak my outer class and its fields, but in my scenario at least it's almost nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's okay, but maybe it's less bad.  Contexts are a particularly heavy thing to leak.  It may not be such a big deal to leak your enclosing class.  Then again, it might.

Basically, Handler leaks occur when Messages are posted with delays.  The Message contains a reference to the Handler, so the Handler remains reachable until the Message is handled.  And note that even without an explicit delay, there may be other tasks in the Looper's queue that must be completed before the Message is handled, so there may be a slight delay.  If the Context (or whatever else your Handler references) becomes invalid during that time, it can lead to errors.

Comment: How would I leak the context, though? In my case, the outer class has literally only two fields (both arrays of strings) and does not extend anything. The handler does, of course, reference a context somehow, but unless I'm mistaken I cannot avoid the handler leaking itself, can I? Whether the handler has a reference to its outer class has no effect on whether it leaks; it simply affects what happens when it does leak.

Comment: The usual way Handlers reference Contexts is by being a non-static inner class of an Activity, and therefore having an implicit reference to the Activity.  It sounds like you understand this.  I didn't mean to imply that your Handler would necessarily leak a Context.